# How to modify type of a local variable in java byte code

Tags: variables, types, local, javassist

I am rewriting bytecode using Javassist. I need to modify type of some local variables to object. How can I access local variables and change their types using Javassist?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This question is quite old but since I did something similar I'll post my solution:

Since I did not found any solution to change the type of a field in a class in Javassist, I just deleted the old method and added a new one with the same name but my desired type:

```
CtClass point = ClassPool.getDefault().get("Point");
CtField toBeDeleted = point .getField("fieldName");
point .removeField(toBeDeleted);
CtField newField = CtField.make("public int fieldName = 0;", point);
point.addField(newField );
```

So with this example I took the field `fieldName` in class `point` that was of type let's say `Object` and know has been changed in a field of type 'int' and initialized to `0`